# Pipe to an existing process

Tags: c

Is it possible to open a pipe to an existing process so I could write stuff to its stdin? Say I launch "gnuplot" from terminal, how would I get a C-language script to write commands to gnuplot?

Comment: Nope, not possible. The target process already has its stdin open and potentially used, you cannot hijack it from under its feet.

Comment: Linux/Unix suggestion: If you can make `gnuplot` take its commands from another source than stdin, you can create a named pipe in the file system, and then write commands to it and let `gnuplot` read from it.

Comment: I add another Linux/Unix suggestion, which I have used myself: use a helping program which runs `gnuplot` as a subprocess, and has full control over what goes to `stdin` of `gnuplot`. One program in this style is `script`, but it only sends on what you type. Another is `expect` which can do tons of things. I wrote a kind of `script` program which could send commands from arbitrary sources to my subprocess.