# Redirecting output to a background task in Linux

Tags: linux

I currently have a background process that is taking in an input, which is generated using another program.

There are a lot of guides on how to redirect output FROM a background process, but may I know if there is a way to redirect output (i.e. generator.py) TO my background process?

An idea of how it may work (but unfortunately doesn't) is:

```
python generator.py | fg
```

Comment: If your background process is called by `bg.sh &` then you can redirect output to it by `python generator.py | bg.sh &`

Comment: Related, possibly dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424497/sending-data-to-stdin-of-another-process-through-linux-terminal

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403759/pipe-to-an-existing-process

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using pipe, where you should be using redirect '<' and '>'.
Pipe is like cascading commands and passing the out put of first to second, second to third, etc...
When using redirect like command 1 < command 2 you are feeding command x with contents of command y. Command 2 can be a file for example,...

Have a read here: https://www.guru99.com/linux-redirection.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).